# Pass an empty unordered_map by default to function in C++

Tags: c++

An empty vector is passed by default by setting it to `{}` in the function definition. How is an empty unordered_map passed by default?

```
int exist(vector<int> a = {}, int x = -1, int y = 10, unordered_map<int,bool> x = ?) {
   ...
}
```

Comment: That is how _any_ argument is default-constructed in an argument list. I don't see how it makes for a useful question about any single type.

Comment: New to C++, did not know that! I am hoping it helps someone else! I asked and answered it since I could not find it with a simple google search

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An empty unordered map and an empty vector are initialized in the same way.

```
int exist(vector<int> a = {}, int x = -1, int y = 10, unordered_map<int,bool> x = {}) {
   ...
}
```